web3.js version 2: requestAirdrop() with 'finalized' confirmation works, but balance afterwards is zero
In web3.js version 2, I am requesting an airdrop with finalized confirmation (the transaction works fine), and then checking the balance (also with finalized) but the balance remains 0:
import {
  createDefaultRpcTransport,
  createSolanaRpcFromTransport,
  generateKeyPair,
  getAddressFromPublicKey,
  lamports,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const user = await generateKeyPair();

const SOL = 1_000_000_000n;

const transport = createDefaultRpcTransport({
  url: "http://localhost:8899",
});

// Create an RPC client using that transport.
const rpc = createSolanaRpcFromTransport(transport);

const address = await getAddressFromPublicKey(user.publicKey);

const amount = lamports(1n * SOL);

const airdropTransactionSignature = await rpc
  .requestAirdrop(address, amount, { commitment: "finalized" })
  .send();
console.log("Airdrop transaction signature", airdropTransactionSignature);

console.log("Getting balance for address", address);

const getBalanceResponse = await rpc
  .getBalance(address, { commitment: "finalized" })
  .send();

console.log("Updated balance for address", address, getBalanceResponse.value);

Starting a local validator with solana-test-validator and running esrun get-airdrop.ts will return:
Airdrop transaction signature w6uhaHSMQyssCc58sqV1KdecCJ7yJtMKj1uDG6Hj7Xr4sjo6cbURbrXjL5L4CsTKW53bd3DS8x7SwmzTLApnYFo
Getting balance for address 5hML2QkSveRRBQuu9pbm34TfoeieBVNBnRsP9Ea97jzP
Updated balance for address 5hML2QkSveRRBQuu9pbm34TfoeieBVNBnRsP9Ea97jzP 0n

Ie there are 0 lamports available in the account.
Using Solana Explorer pointed at localhost, I can see the Balance (SOL) ◎1 at the 5hML2QkSveRRBQuu9pbm34TfoeieBVNBnRsP9Ea97jzP address, so the airdrop is eventually happening. The airdrop is just not ready to use once the transaction confirms, which is unexpected.
How can I know when the airdrop is available to use?

The way to handle this using version 2 of @solana/web3.js is by using the airdropFactory method.
I've adapted your script to make it work using this method and it now returns with the balance available to be used.
import {
  airdropFactory,
  createDefaultRpcTransport,
  createSolanaRpc,
  createSolanaRpcFromTransport,
  createSolanaRpcSubscriptions,
  generateKeyPair,
  getAddressFromPublicKey,
  lamports,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const user = await generateKeyPair();

const SOL = 1_000_000_000n;

const rpc = createSolanaRpc("http://localhost:8899");
const rpcSubscriptions = createSolanaRpcSubscriptions("ws://localhost:8900");
const airdrop = airdropFactory({ rpc, rpcSubscriptions });

const address = await getAddressFromPublicKey(user.publicKey);

const amount = lamports(1n * SOL);

const airdropTransactionSignature = await airdrop({
  commitment: "finalized",
  recipientAddress: address,
  lamports: amount,
});

console.log("Airdrop transaction signature", airdropTransactionSignature);

console.log("Getting balance for address", address);

const getBalanceResponse = await rpc
  .getBalance(address, { commitment: "finalized" })
  .send();

console.log("Updated balance for address", address, getBalanceResponse.value);

returns:
Airdrop transaction signature AsGDKxEuq3Fxf7vFzSQaHS5bjdE9fztcGLonsAio7DpzBojMS5gtxMBJLxxhVFWeaARr2TYnNR18HsNt2qf3D9N
Getting balance for address 86EzM5asZJiQnVxpKaqDDZte6KNoMZKry73r5XJHymAX
Updated balance for address 86EzM5asZJiQnVxpKaqDDZte6KNoMZKry73r5XJHymAX 1000000000n


Thanks for finding a workaround! But I don't think "The way to handle this using version 2 of @solana/web3.js is by using the airdropFactory method." is correct. The web3.js verson 2 docs repeatedly refer to requestAirdrop() and if requestAirdrop doesn't work, it shouldn't exist!

Filed: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/3683

The answer is correct. The rpc.requestAirdrop method just mirrors the JSON-RPC method, which returns the signature but doesn't wait for it to confirm. TBH I'm not sure what the commitment param there does! It exists because we want to provide types for every RPC method. But if you want to request airdrop + wait for it to confirm, that's what the new airdropFactory is for

@CallumM "TBH I'm not sure what the commitment param there does!" then it sounds like the commitment parameter should be deleted or made to work as expected.

I've responded in more detail with an Agave code reference on your Github issue, which is definitely a better place for this than these comments!
